# 'CREATE PROCEDURE' must be the only statement in the batch (Erro)

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I'm creating this table but I'm running into a problem with the first procedure (sp_joseview)

```
create table josecustomer(
name varchar(50),
address varchar(300),
ssnid int,
balance bigint,
accountnumber bigint
)

insert into josecustomer values('Aman','Canada',10000,5000,100000000)
insert into josecustomer values('Shubham','USA',10001,6000,200000000)
insert into josecustomer values('Himanshu','Australia',10002,2000,300000000)
insert into josecustomer values('Jose','India',10003,3000,400000000)
insert into josecustomer values('Albert','Brazil',10004,4000,500000000)
insert into josecustomer values('Peterson','Germany',10005,7000,600000000)
insert into josecustomer values('Adam','Honkong',10006,8000,700000000)
insert into josecustomer values('William','Paris',10007,9000,800000000)

select * from josecustomer

create proc sp_joseview
as begin
select * from josecustomer
end
go

create proc sp_updatejose
(@accountno bigint,@newbalance bigint)
as begin
update josecustomer 
set balance=@newbalance
where accountnumber=@accountno
end 
go
```

There is a syntax error showing for the first procedure but I can't figure out what that error might be.

Comment: Put a `Go` after your `Select * from josecustomer`.  The error is self-explanatory...

Comment: add "as begin" and "end" for the first stored procedure - in addition to "Go" advised before.

Comment: @PawelCz thats already there, and not the cause of this error. See 2 identical answers.

Comment: @HoneyBadger it is not clear at all unless  you understand 'batch' in this context and how to mark them. Joe, batch terminator is 'GO' for SQL Server tools. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 25):

The error is self-explanatory - you cannot issue a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement unless it's the only statement in the batch.

In SSMS the `GO` keyword splits the statement into separate batches, so you need to add one after the statement before the `CREATE PROCEDURE`:

```
create table josecustomer(
name varchar(50),
address varchar(300),
ssnid int,
balance bigint,
accountnumber bigint
)

insert into josecustomer values('Aman','Canada',10000,5000,100000000)
insert into josecustomer values('Shubham','USA',10001,6000,200000000)
insert into josecustomer values('Himanshu','Australia',10002,2000,300000000)
insert into josecustomer values('Jose','India',10003,3000,400000000)
insert into josecustomer values('Albert','Brazil',10004,4000,500000000)
insert into josecustomer values('Peterson','Germany',10005,7000,600000000)
insert into josecustomer values('Adam','Honkong',10006,8000,700000000)
insert into josecustomer values('William','Paris',10007,9000,800000000)

select * from josecustomer
Go  --Add a Go here

create proc sp_joseview
as begin
select * from josecustomer
end
go

create proc sp_updatejose
(@accountno bigint,@newbalance bigint)
as begin
update josecustomer 
set balance=@newbalance
where accountnumber=@accountno
end 
go
```

Answer (score 12):

The keyword `GO` separates batches in a single script. The error says that a `CREATE PROCEDURE` must be the "only" statement in a batch so it stands to reason you're missing a `GO` above a `CREATE PROCEDURE` somewhere.

Now look at your script, its separated into 4 broad areas

1. create a table
2. insert some data (and select it out again)
3. create proc 1
4. create proc 2

Its clear that you're missing a `go` between 2. and 3.