# SQL create Stored procedure to delete

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Im trying to delete a project via a stored procedure i am receiving an error stating

> Incorrect syntax:'CREATE PROCEDURE' must be the only statement in the
>   batch.

Any suggestions to my code?

```
create procedure SP_DeleteProject
(
@projectId char(4)
)
as
begin
delete from Project where projectId = @projectId;
end
go
```

Comment: This code on its own is fine, but probably you have some code above this as well? The error seems quite clear - the CREATE PROCEDURE must be the only statement within a single batch (a batch being denoted by the GO statement). And please tag the correct DB (I'm guessing SQL Server...but...). And always google your error before posting a question -
 there are hundreds of links about this particular one, including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022645/create-procedure-must-be-the-only-statement-in-the-batch-erro

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code attempt is product specific.)

Comment: This runs fine as is. You probably have more stuff you aren't including here.

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of or very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022645/create-procedure-must-be-the-only-statement-in-the-batch-erro

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server but i figured it out there are other stored procedures ahead of it that didn't have the go at the end

Answer (score 2):

1. is that the only script that you are running on the editor ?
   if yes then I would try and rename the procedure name
   if no then I would put a GO statement in front of Create Procedure

Comment: This really isn't an answer.

Comment: @dfundako Why is this not an answer? I even tend to agree with Fancy5g that a simple `GO` (before the first line) is likely to solve this case for the OP.

Comment: I lean towards answers that ask for more clarifying info as half-answers. Hence why I didn't downvote or use absolute language. Just my opinion.  The GO part is valid, though.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19133386)

Comment: @dfundako But it was the answer and was posted before the OP said it was the answer.  OP should give this the check mark.

Comment: @MP24 But according to the OP it is indeed the answer